# Java Input scanner to array multidimensional

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I want to display an array of input that I input. and in print automatically. I want to display the array of input values ​​that I input. and will be printed automatically.

my code like this :

```
public class ReadArray {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input total row : ");
int row = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Input total column : ");
int column = sc.nextInt();

int [][] matrix = new int[row][column];
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        System.out.println("Row ["+i+"]:  Column "+j+" :");
    matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt(); 
}

}



    }

}
```

I want results like this :

Input total row : 2
Input total column : 2

Row [0]:  Column  0 :
1

Row [0]:  Column 1 :
2

Row [1]:  Column  0 :
10

Row [1]:  Column 1 :
11

Data Array 1 : 1,2
Data Array 2 : 10,11

anyone can help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   String result="";//this variable for the last line which print the result
   for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
     result=result+"Data Array "+i+" :";
       for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
         System.out.println("Row [" + i + "]:  Column " + j + " :");
         matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
         result=result+matrix[i][j]+", ";

        }

    }
System.out.println(result);////for the final result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
    System.out.println("Row ["+i+"]:  Column "+j+" :");
    matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt(); //Storing input value here    
    System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);//Output the input value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The  code is as follows

```
        for (int i = 0; i < baris; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {

    // print array data to screen
                System.out.println("Data Array "+(i+1) +matrix[i][j]);

        }
System.out.println();
}
```

I hope this code is help you so Please review it .

Answer (score 0):

- Print the row and col number and then the entre the matix data and
  print it in matrix form

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  ```
      System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Rows");

      int row = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Columns");

      int col = scan.nextInt();

      //defining 2D array to hold matrix data
      int[][] matrix = new int[row][col];
      // Enter Matrix Data
      enterMatrixData(scan, matrix, row, col);

      // Print Matrix Data
      printMatrixData(matrix, row, col);
  ```

  }   public static void enterMatrixData(Scanner scan, int[][] matrix, int row, int col){

  ```
   System.out.println("Enter Matrix Data");

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
  ```

  }

  public static void printMatrixData(int[][] matrix, int row, int col){

  System.out.println("Your Matrix is : ");

  ```
      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
          {
              System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+"\t");
          }

          System.out.println();
      }
  ```

  }